# Regex for Singapore Addresses

Tags: java, android, regex

I am doing Android. I have been googling for regex formula to validate Singapore addresses. I have come across many regex pattern but all did not work for me, as most are for US addresses.

The current regex pattern that I am using now is:

```
\d{1,3}.?\d{0,3}\s[a-zA-Z]{2,30}\s[a-zA-Z]{2,15}
```

which did not do much. Below are a few sample of Singapore addresses:

- `2 Orchard Turn #B4-47 ION ORCHARD Singapore 238801`
- `68 Marine Parade Road #03-26B parkway Parade 449269`
- `Nanyang Polytechnic 180 Ang Mo Kio Avenue 8 Singapore 569830`

*Additional Notes*: The postal code (6 digit numbers behind) will appear for every addresses

**------------------------------------------------EDIT----------------------------------------**

I need a regex that can detect and extract an address from a text output, that has other information as well.

For example:

```
Jean Watson
Managing Director

+65 96622235
68 Marine Parade Road #03-26B parkway Parade 449269
```

Comment: Step 1: put into words the rules you want to validate, before you even start working on a regexp. What are you exactly trying to ascertain? "String ends in 6 digits"? Something more complicated? Your regexp says "some digits, then maybe anything, then maybe some more digits, a space, a potentially long word, a space, a possibly shorter word", which does not resemble your example addresses at all. When you formulate your *problem* well, you will get the answer, too.

Comment: What @Amadan said.  Also crucial information is: out of what data do you want to identify these addresses?  Can you provide example data that should *not* match in addition to the samples of what should match?

Comment: `.+\d{6}` This simplest regex will match `everything` followed by a `6 digit` postal code. As your address doesn't have a fixed pattern I used `.+` A small [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vV3iV1/1) is here. But I will suggest you to come up with a rule for matching.

Comment: What if i want to extract the unit number only from the above text such as #03-26B or #B4-47?

Answer (score 1):

I have this for you :)  satisfy your all 3 inputs

```
  (\d{1,3}.)?.+\s(\d{6})$
```

#### See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gU2rY4/1)

> Regex Explanation:

**(\d{1,3}.)** - this matches at-least 1 or max 3 digits

**?** - makes it 0 or 1

**.+** - matches any character 1 or more times

**\s** - matches single white space

**(\d{6})$** - matches ends with 6 digits

Comment: Please explain to improve your ans

Comment: @NJ Hi totally new to regular expression what if i want to extract the unit number only from the above text such as #03-26B or #B4-47 in Singapore address context? Then recombine it with another string text with $result=$googleAddress.$unitNum;

Comment: @NJ really need some help here if you help? Trying ^#\w{1,4}.+(\w{1,4})$ without much luck

Comment: @Vivian post new question rather than commenting on an old question.

Comment: how your out put will be. i mean i checked with you fiddle. it only says invalid code...what should i enter to test

Comment: @steve if you look at the OP post he need to identify the address line *68 Marine Parade Road #03-26B parkway Parade 449269* is highlighted as result of regex match.

Comment: oh i need to enter the whole 68 Marine Parade Road #03-26B parkway Parade 449269

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern:

```
^.+?(?<!\d)\d{6}$
```

Will match lines which:

1. start with a digit (one or more) followed by .)
2. end with 6 digits (postcode)

Comment: But "Nanyang Polytechnic" from OP's examples does not start with a digit. That's the problem: the problem is not formulated at all.

Comment: the pattern will capture the "Nanyang Polytechnic" line as it starts with "3.)" hence matching the ^\d+\.\), the pattern will then capture anything up to (and including) the post code at the end of the line, Did you want to exclude the 3.) from being captured?

Comment: the "3.)" is just me using it to list out the examples :D , it is not part of the example. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Why did you used  `*` after `.` and why made it optional by using `?` ? Address part will have at least one character.

Comment: yes i should have used `.+?\d{6}$` as there will always be more than 1 character. I made it not greedy so it stops at the first $ as I thought this might be a whole block of text., Since 1.) not part of the text that @MattDonalds will work with, I think `^.+\d{6}$` like suggested before is a better option

Comment: @noob Hi, your answer is correct. However, I forgot to add in that I need to extract the address from a text output that contains other details as well. **Please check my edit**, for '.+?\d{6}$', it will also take '+65 96622235' as the address. Sorry for not specifying it clearly in the beginning ~

Comment: `^.+?(?<!\d)\d{6}$` will exclude lines with more than 6 digits at the end or also `^.+?\s\d{6}$` should work assuming that the 6 digit postcode is preceded by a space

Comment: It does not work perfectly, but since it meet the requirement by the postal code part, I will accept it. Please update your answer, so that I can accept this :)